# std::unique_ptr and QObject::deleteLater

Tags: qt, c++11

I would like my std::unique_ptr to call QObject::deleteLater to destruct the object.

I can't figure out how to do it.

Nothing I tried compiles.

E.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<SomeQObject, decltype(&QObject::deleteLater)> var(
                pointer, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

Please help...

**Addition #1.**

OK, I've found that this works:

```
std::unique_ptr<QObject, decltype(std::mem_fun(&QObject::deleteLater))> var(
            pointer,
            std::mem_fun(&QObject::deleteLater));
```

Instead of this one:

```
std::unique_ptr<QObject, decltype(&QObject::deleteLater)> var(
            pointer,
            QObject::deleteLater);
```

But it's too ugly for me to use it. Is there a good way?

Comment: Have you tried removing the & before QObject::deleteLater. I am not sure if the template argument wants a pointer or a function itself.

Comment: I've tried all the possible variants.

Comment: In that case I would write a trivial template function wrapper around deletelater which takes an object and calls deletelater method on it.

Comment: IE: `template<typename T> function deleteLaterFunc(T foo) { foo.deleteLater() }` or some variant.

Comment: you are stuck with std::bind, std::mem_fun or lambda, you can't just use member func pointer in this context just because unique_ptr tries to be more generic and expects a callable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's very very simple and straightforward, by the way.

```
struct QObjectDeleteLater {
    void operator()(QObject *o) {
        o->deleteLater();
    }
};

template<typename T>
using qobject_delete_later_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, QObjectDeleteLater>;
```

Usage:

```
qobject_delete_later_unique_ptr<QObject> ptr(new QFooBar);
```

Bonus points if you can come up with a sensible name...

Answer (score 1):

As [doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) says it :

> Type requirements
>
> -Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an
>   argument of type unique_ptr::pointer

You are 'stuck' here with std::bind, std::mem_fun or lambda, you can't just use member func pointer in this context because its not satisfying requirements

---

lambda version:

```
  auto deleter = [](QObject* obj) {obj->deleteLater();};
  std::unique_ptr<QObject, decltype(deleter)> x(new QObject(), deleter);
```

Comment: It seems it's something evident to you. But I'm still do not understand. Is there a nice way to use QScopedPinter/std::unique_ptr with QObject::deleteLater deletor?

Comment: but you gave one in your question